# How can a circuit breaker turn on a different circuit?

Tags: circuit-breaker

So I recently bought a house built in the 70's and been dealing with issues ever since. Recently I was going to do some work with the electrical in the master bedroom when I ran into a problem and now I'm lost. Here's the easy way to explain what's happening

In this order:

- Turn off breaker 9 master lights turn off
- Turn off breaker 11 outside plugs turn off
- Turn on breaker 11 outside plugs and master lights turn on
- Now only turn off breaker 11 only outside plugs turn off.

Any suggestions or help is appreciated.

UPDATE

So I have traced the outside plug back to breaker 11 it's is a straight shot through crawl space no splits or junction boxes, I'm assuming this means the box needs to be replaced? If so any suggestions on brands to buy/avoid?

Update 2

So the last update was wrong I have no clue what in my house breaker 11 is powering and while checking I heard arcing in the box shut main power, electrician came out got the box operable for the time being and working with insurance to replace it

Here's some images of what the electrician found:

[image: burnt stabs]

[image: more burnt stabs]

[image: whole panel shot]

[image: 9 & 11 up close]

Comment: What happens when you turn off both breakers, then turn on breaker 9 then turn it back off again?

Comment: Also, what make and model is the electrical panel in your place?

Comment: Break 9 will control the master lights like it is supposed to and the brand is ITE not sure of model.

Comment: https://m.imgur.com/esahcgR this is my panel for reference

Comment: Does the handle of breaker 9 change position when you turn breaker 11 back on?

Comment: No the lights just come back on

Comment: If 9 breaker is off with 11 on and master lights on, are you reading voltage on 9 output screw terminal.   If you move breaker 9 or 11 in the panel (for example move 11 to 13) does the issue still follow.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel correct me if I am mistaken but 9 and 11 should both be on L1 buss, so 9 would not be affected by a back feed from 11, so only way to see if back feed exists is to meter with 9 off.

Comment: I haven't tried yet and will have to in the morning.

Comment: @spicetraders -- they're actually on opposite busses (11 is directly below 9 on this panel -- adjacent slots vertically are on opposite busses, which is what allows 2 pole breakers to work)

Comment: This is beneath breaker 11 http://imgur.com/pkXxHW6 but the breaker it self has no marks on it

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel yup brain shutdown, it is just to late at night, should have quit when I put on the glasses cause I could no longer see the screen..

Comment: You might want to get an Electrician in to inspect the panel.  Looks like there was some type of explosion in the empty slot in your photo, which usually suggests arcing (which leads to fires).  If the breakers are loose and arcing, it's not so good.

Comment: I wonder if the slot below breaker 11 was where one of the two breakers 9/11 at originally

Comment: Your update trace of 11s wire clears the wire itself, but how many outlets are on the outside.

Comment: @spicetraders - One outlet outside

Comment: On the power panel, bottom left side, is that black wire actually going in with all the other wires?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your box, sadly, is toast -- I suspect the mismatched circuit breakers (you have an ITE/Siemens box which uses type QP breakers, yet there are BR and HOM aliens roaming around in it, which is *bad* as while 1" breakers may appear to fit in other folks 1" type panelboards, they certainly won't fit *well*!) are part of why you're seeing the arcing and burning on the bus tabs.

As to what's going on with breakers 9 and 11? Have your electrician measure for a short between the two circuits with them both disconnected from their breakers in the panel and tagged.  (If he's really good, you might be able to get them meggered even -- this will find "leakage paths" between them in addition to "hard" connections, but requires gizmos to be unplugged and light bulbs removed from the circuits lest something fry from the HV an insulation tester applies to the circuit under test.)  If you see a short or leakage path, then that's your culprit, and it's time to basically trace, divide, and conquer at that point.

Answer (score 2):

I am really suspecting that someone has hooked a grounded conductor(slang neutral/white ) wire to a hot wire 
Say in a light socket where the white wire was used as the pwer wire for the light fixture and it wa snot taped off to show it was the hot
 A white wire was hooked to it thinking it was a neutral
 I fought a problem like this for weeks in a building. Someone had done this to several runs 
 It could be in any junction box, at a light switch ,an outlet or even in the breaker panel

Most likely you will only have to work these three circuts
 Another idea is someone tried to do a multiwire circuit and got it mixed up or a three way switch was replaced with the wrong switch and to make it work they wired some wires to others

I would start by taking stuff apart like outlets one at a time and see when problem goes away or take fixtures loose one at at time
 Last you could have a two circuits doing the same thing